# Starling Flash automation

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, automation

Has anybody of you tried automation of Starling (http://gamua.com/starling/) automation?
For ordinary AS3 applications I use Genie (http://sourceforge.net/adobe/genie/wiki/Home/), unfortunately this solution doesn't work with Starling app. Genie server connects to the app, but cannot find any elements.
Do you have any other solutions (not based on image-recognition)?

Comment: Nice question! Would like to know more :)

Answer (score 0):

Since Starling like any Stage3D based framework cannot catch directly user interaction, automation is of course difficult to implement. Stage3D does not respond to user interaction, no mouse event, touch event, so Starling has to fake those event based on what happen on the stage (global), as a result there's only one object in a starling app that respond to user interaction and it's the stage itself meaning the entire screen. Automation cannot work with this of course. The only solution would be o plug a custom framework (not Event based since Starling is not Event based) directly to the Starling fake event dispatching and go from there. That custom framework can only be made especially for Starling because all event in Starling are not based on the Flash Event system.

Answer (score 0):

There is fresh (3 months) topic in [Starling forum](https://forum.starling-framework.org/topic/tdd-and-unit-testing-where-to-start) about the subject:

1.

> Starling and Feathers both use FlexUnit, so looking at how we do it
>   might be a good place to start!
>
> https://github.com/Gamua/Starling-Framework/tree/master/tests
>   https://github.com/BowlerHatLLC/feathers/tree/master/test

2.

> Tutorial by Adobe:
>   http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/articles/flashbuilder4_tdd.html

3.

> Check out our new project BreezeTest
>   (https://github.com/GetBreeze/breeze-test). It was build specifically
>   for testing AIR apps, supports asynchronous testing and is really easy
>   to get started. We use it to do automated tests on our all
>   https://www.getbreeze.io libraries via TravisCI.